# Making a Twilio outgoing call, playing an mp3 menu, then listen/gather digits the receiver dials as response

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

Im working with The Twilio Api and I have this code:

```
      def call
       @phone = params[:phone]
       @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@@account_sid, @@auth_token)

       @call = @client.account.calls.create(
        :from => '+805XXXXX',   # From your Twilio number
        :to => '+1' + @phone ,     # To any number
        :url => 'http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient'
       )

       Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
         r.Gather numDigits: '1', action: menu_path do |g|
          g.say "Thank you for your time", loop: 3
         end
       end.text

     end
```

My goal is to start the outgoing call, then the call receiver will be prompted to enter digits 1  or 2, but I don't know how to listen to the client receiving the call. I know "Gather" listens to the digits entered, but I cant get it right. Does anyone have an idea of how I could accomplish this?

here is the menu_path method

```
    def menu_selection
      user_selection = params[:Digits]

      case user_selection
      when "1"
        @output = "Thank you for your time Have a good day"
        twiml_say(@output, true)
      when "2"
        @output = "One of our representatives will call you soon"
        twiml_say(@output, true)   
     else
      @output = "Returning to the main menu."
      twiml_say(@output)
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you make a call with Twilio you give a URL parameter, as you have done in your example. When Twilio connects the call, Twilio makes an HTTP request to that URL to ask what to do next. That is where you need to return TwiML, as you have tried to do in your call method.

Currently your code sends a URL that will play holding music to the person who answers the phone. Instead, you need to break apart that call method and send Twilio a URL that your application will be able to respond to with the TwiML from the second part of the method.

```
  def call
   @phone = params[:phone]
   @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@@account_sid, @@auth_token)

   @call = @client.account.calls.create(
    :from => '+805XXXXX',   # From your Twilio number
    :to => '+1' + @phone ,     # To any number
    :url => twiml_path
   )

   # redirect or something here.

 end

 def twiml
   twiml_response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
     r.Gather numDigits: '1', action: menu_path do |g|
      g.say "Thank you for your time", loop: 3
     end
   end
   render :xml => twiml_response.to_xml
 end
```

Your menu_selection path looks fine as it is.

If you want to read more on using [Twilio with Rails, this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html) is a useful start. For a more indepth look at [using `<Gather>` to create an IVR (phone menu) this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-phone-tree/ruby/rails#0) will help you out.

Comment: Thanks you Philnash this worked perfect .  This was very helpful .

Comment: No problem! Give us a shout on Stack Overflow if you have any other questions.